# Proper way to archive large JSON objects in a PostgreSQL table that will be API accessible?

Tags: postgresql

I've been working at this problem for a bit now. I'm working on a statistics website as a hobby for a game that I play.

Basically I have a script accessing the game's API every 5 minutes (probably going to increase this to 15 minutes) and pulling the current state of all the matches at once. I was originally storing this object as a JSON column in my table. (Each row then had a 118kb object in the JSON column)

The problem was trying to query the table to get the entire archive for a one week period (which is the duration of the match). Basically, it was pulling 2016 118kb records for a week long match-up when all I wanted was a specific key out of the JSON. Requests to this API endpoint are taking about 10 seconds to complete!

I've only found ways in PostgreSQL to query a row based on a JSON key, but not a way to do something like `SELECT match.kills FROM matches WHERE...`.

I've realized that that's not going to work so I want to try to take keys from the JSON objects and insert them into the corresponding table column.

The JSON object skeleton looks like this:

```
{
  id: string,
  start_time: timestamp,
  end_time: timestamp,
  scores: {
    green: number,
    blue: number,
    red: number 
  },
  worlds: number[],
  all_worlds: number[][],
  deaths: {
    green: number,
    blue: number,
    red: number
  },
  kills: {
    green: number,
    blue: number,
    red: number
  },
  maps: [
    {
      id: number,
      type: string,
      scores: same as above,
      bonuses: {
        type: string,
        owner: string
      },
      deaths: same as above,
      kills: same as above,
      objectives: [
        {
          id: string,
          type: string,
          owner: string,
          last_flipped: timestamp,
          claimed_by: guild id (put this into another api endpoint),
          claimed_at: timestamp
        },
        ... (repeat 17 times)
      ]
    },
    ... (repeat 3 times)
  ]
}
```

So I want to store this in my database with the keys as columns, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish it for keys with values of the type `object`.

The end goal is to store this in a way that I'll have an API accessible by a URL such as:

`mywebsite.com/api/v1/matcharchive?data=kills,deaths,score&matchid=1-1&archive_time=2016-07-09T02:00:00Z`

and it will query the database for only those 3 keys in the object and return them.

What is the proper way to store a JSON object with this many keys into a PSQL table?

Comment: If the data is well structured as in the example then JSON is not a good option. In instead go for plain normalization.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. From a google search, it looks like you're talking about having multiple tables for different parts, for example a maps table, an objectives table, etc?

Comment: Yes search for database normalization.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `->` operator on the json field.  This example is slightly edited so the auto-increment keys are a little off.

```
host=# create table tmp1 ( id serial primary key, data json);
CREATE TABLE
host=# \d tmp1
                         Table "public.tmp1"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('tmp1_id_seq'::regclass)
 data   | json    | 
Indexes:
    "tmp1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

host=# insert into tmp1 (data) values ('{"a":1, "b":2}'), ('{"a":3, "b":4}'), ('{"a":5, "c":6}');
INSERT 0 3
host=# select * from tmp1;
 id |      data      
----+----------------
  2 | {"a":1, "b":2}
  3 | {"a":3, "b":4}
  4 | {"a":5, "c":6}
(3 rows)   

host=# select id, data->'b' from tmp1;
 id | ?column?
----+----------
  2 | 2
  3 | 4
  4 |
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I did not see anything like this while looking around. I think this will actually take care of my problem. I will mark this question as answered when I have a chance to test this more tomorrow.

Comment: I googled "postgresql json operators" and got this manual page:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html .  There are other accessors for json values there.

Comment: It looks like this is going to work perfectly for my needs. Marking the question as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: It's also a good idea to use a `jsonb` field instead of `json`, since it is almost exactly the same except smaller and faster for this sort of thing.  It might put the key-value objects into a different order, but it won't reorder arrays.

Comment: Ok, I've altered the table column to be jsonb and tested it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before and after and it does seem to be faster on average. Thanks for this!